# LayoutTemplate Error In Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

i have a login and register form when i click on register form link button then it shows me error like this i.e PARSE ERROR
when i click on register link it shows me error

```
         Parser Error Message: Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard' does
           not have a public property named 'LayoutTemplate'.

        Source Error:


            Line 6:  <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server"
             ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
           Line 7:      <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="RegisterUser" runat="server" 
              EnableViewState="false" OnCreatedUser="RegisterUser_CreatedUser">

           Line 8:          <LayoutTemplate>
         Line 9:              <asp:PlaceHolder ID="wizardStepPlaceholder"     
           runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
              Line 10:             <asp:PlaceHolder ID="navigationPlaceholder" 
            runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

CODE IN REGISTER.ASPX IN HTML

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="RegisterUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" 
            OnCreatedUser="RegisterUser_CreatedUser">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="wizardStepPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="navigationPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="RegisterUserWizardStep" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <h2>
                    Create a New Account
                </h2>
                <p>
                    Use the form below to create a new account.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Passwords are required to be a minimum of <%= 
            Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength %> characters in length.
                </p>
                <span class="failureNotification">
                    <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                </span>
                <asp:ValidationSummary ID="RegisterUserValidationSummary" 
            runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" 
                     ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup"/>
                <div class="accountInfo">
                    <fieldset class="register">
                        <legend>Account Information</legend>
                        <p>
                            <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server"
          AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" 
           CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired"
           runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" 
                                 CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="User 
             Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." 
                                 ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup">*
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" 
                    AssociatedControlID="Email">E-mail:</asp:Label>

                            <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" 
                      CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>

                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequired" 
                  runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email" 
                                 CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="E-mail
                      is required." ToolTip="E-mail is required." 
                                 ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup">*
                          </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" 
           AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" 
                   CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" 
                   runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" 
                                 CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Password 
                  is required." ToolTip="Password is required." 
                                 ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup">*
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <asp:Label ID="ConfirmPasswordLabel" runat="server" 
              AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password:</asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" 
              CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
                 ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" CssClass="failureNotification
                     Display="Dynamic" 

                                 ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." 
                  ID="ConfirmPasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                 ToolTip="Confirm Password is required." 
                   ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup">*
                      </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordCompare" runat="server" 
            ControlToCompare="Password" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" 
                                 CssClass="failureNotification" Display="Dynamic"
               ErrorMessage="The Password and Confirmation Password must match."
                                 ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup">*
                    </asp:CompareValidator>
                        </p>
                    </fieldset>
                    <p class="submitButton">
                        <asp:Button ID="CreateUserButton" runat="server" 
                      CommandName="MoveNext" Text="Create User" 
                             ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup"/>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <CustomNavigationTemplate>
            </CustomNavigationTemplate>
        </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
    </WizardSteps>
</asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

HOW I REMOVE THIS ERROR FROM FORM ANY HELP?

Comment: LayoutTemplate is available from version 4.0 onwards. What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: yes i use 3.5 so what i will do with this error?

Answer (score 4):

LayoutTemplate is available from version 4.0 onwards. If you comment out the code corresponding lines from your code, you should be able to successfully compile it.

**EDIT:** I noticed that your code does not contain the declaration for Security Question and Answer fields, which is causing the exception to be thrown. You can add in the required fields as shown in the [code sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on MSDN for version 3.5.

Comment: when i comment it shows me error...RegisterUser: CreateUserWizardStep.ContentTemplate does not contain an IEditableTextControl with ID Question for the security question, this is required if your membership provider requires a question and answer.

Comment: Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: RegisterUser: CreateUserWizardStep.ContentTemplate does not contain an IEditableTextControl with ID Question for the security question, this is required if your membership provider requires a question and answer.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.